# Javascript time validator with time intervals?

Tags: javascript, validation, time

I need a function in javascript, `function isTime(timeString)` that can validate the format of an input field.

I need this to be of the format hh:mm and need the validation to be of intervals of 10.

```
So valid examples are:

10:00
12:10
13:20
14:30
13:40
14:50
...
```

And

```
Invalid examples are:

10:05
11:13
14:23
22:45
...
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried? Before we can help you!

Comment: Is `24:00` acceptable?

Comment: a very simple solution would be `/\d\d:\d0/.test('10:00')`, though it does not validate the that the time is valid.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy yes it is acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/y7RFR/

The following function should work for your time validation in 24-hour format.

```
function validateTime(){
   var inputTime = document.getElementById('inputTime');

   var pattern = new RegExp("^\\d*[0-2]\\d:\\d*[0-5]0$");

   if(inputTime.value){
       var splittedTime = inputTime.value.split(':');
       if(splittedTime[0] <= 23){
           if(inputTime.value.match(pattern)){
               alert('Valid Time.');
           }else{
               alert('Invalid Time.');
           } 
       }else{
           alert('Invalid Time.');
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, the minutes is working exactly as i need it to. However i need the hours to "stop" after 23. F.eks. 27:50 returns "Valid time" this should be invalid. Can you help with that? @Parkash

Comment: @Beer Funding See my changes in http://jsfiddle.net/y7RFR/